# Aligning bootstrap columns to fall on top of another column in same row Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, view

I am trying to align my bootstrap column where it says TEST to go underneath the Build information column, but it just goes to the bottom of the screen. I just can't figure out how to achieve this. I have followed many tutorials but always ends up on the bottom left. Can anybody help? Thanks.

[image: Demo]

Here is my code...

```
<div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-7">
                            <div class="card w-100">
                                <h5 class="card-header">Single Stage Terminal</h5>
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <div class="container">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-4" style="font-weight:bolder">
                                                Order Number:
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                                <strong>@Model.OrderNumber</strong>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <span class="br"></span>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-4" style="font-weight:bolder">
                                                Stage:
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                                <strong> @Model.Stage</strong>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <span class="br"></span>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-4" style="font-weight:bolder">
                                                Item Number:
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                                <strong> @Model.ItemNumber</strong>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <span class="br"></span>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-4" style="font-weight:bolder">
                                                Description:
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                                <strong> @Model.Description</strong>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <span class="br"></span>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-4" style="font-weight:bolder">
                                                Build Standard:
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                                <strong> @Model.BuildStandard</strong>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <span class="br"></span>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-4" style="font-weight:bolder">
                                                Priority:
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                                <strong> @Model.Priority</strong>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <span class="br"></span>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-4" style="font-weight:bolder">
                                                Process Trial:
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                                <strong> @Model.ProcessTrial</strong>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <span class="br"></span>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-4" style="font-weight:bolder">
                                                Parent Item:
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                                <strong> @Model.ParentItem &nbsp; </strong><b style="color:forestgreen; margin-left:50px;">@Model.LeadFree</b>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <span class="br"></span>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-4" style="font-weight:bolder">
                                                Order Status:
                                            </div>
                                            <span class="br"></span>
                                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                                <strong> @Model.OrderStatus</strong>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="card-body w-100 border" style="margin-right:1px;">
                                            <span class="blinking" style="color:red; margin-left:1px;">@Model.WarningCheck</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-5">
                            <div class="card w-100">
                                <h5 class="card-header">Build Information</h5>
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <div class="container">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-6" style="font-weight:bolder">
                                                DR Order Quantity:
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                <strong style="text-align:center">@Model.DrOrderQty</strong>
                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                        <span class="br"></span>


                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-6" style="font-weight:bolder">
                                                Allocated:
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                <strong> @Model.Allocated</strong>
                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                        <span class="br"></span>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-6" style="font-weight:bolder">
                                                Scanned Quantity:
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                <strong> @Model.ScannedQty</strong>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <span class="br"></span>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-6" style="font-weight:bolder">
                                                Remaining:
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                <strong> @Model.Remaining</strong>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <span class="br"></span>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-6" style="font-weight:bolder">
                                                Total Std Hours:
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                <strong> @Model.TotalStdHrs</strong>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <span class="br"></span>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-6" style="font-weight:bolder">
                                                Schedule:
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                <strong> @Model.Ok</strong>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-5">
                            <div class="card w-100">
                                <h5 class="card-header">TEST</h5>
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <div class="container">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-6" style="font-weight:bolder">
                                                DR Order Quantity:
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                <strong style="text-align:center">@Model.DrOrderQty</strong>
                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                        <span class="br"></span>


                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-6" style="font-weight:bolder">
                                                Allocated:
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                <strong> @Model.Allocated</strong>
                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                        <span class="br"></span>
                                     </div>
                                 </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

I also putting the test column into a new row and appending row justify-content-end but that just puts my text column on the right side but under both elements

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue, i needed to just add a nested row within the column

[image]

[image]

```
<div class="col-lg-5">
                            <div class="card w-100">
                                <h5 class="card-header">Build Information</h5>
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <div class="container">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-6" style="font-weight:bolder">
                                                DR Order Quantity:
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                <strong style="text-align:center">@Model.DrOrderQty</strong>
                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                        <span class="br"></span>


                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-6" style="font-weight:bolder">
                                                Allocated:
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                <strong> @Model.Allocated</strong>
                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                        <span class="br"></span>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-6" style="font-weight:bolder">
                                                Scanned Quantity:
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                <strong> @Model.ScannedQty</strong>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <span class="br"></span>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-6" style="font-weight:bolder">
                                                Remaining:
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                <strong> @Model.Remaining</strong>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <span class="br"></span>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-6" style="font-weight:bolder">
                                                Total Std Hours:
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                <strong> @Model.TotalStdHrs</strong>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <span class="br"></span>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-6" style="font-weight:bolder">
                                                Schedule:
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                <strong> @Model.Ok</strong>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <div class="card w-100">
                                    <h5 class="card-header">TEST</h5>
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <div class="container">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-sm-6" style="font-weight:bolder">
                                                    DR Order Quantity:
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                    <strong style="text-align:center">@Model.DrOrderQty</strong>
                                                </div>

                                            </div>
                                            <span class="br"></span>


                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-sm-6" style="font-weight:bolder">
                                                    Allocated:
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                    <strong> @Model.Allocated</strong>
                                                </div>

                                            </div>
                                            <span class="br"></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```